# Site Performance and Download

Tags: performance, web

I am wanting to find an automated way to download an entire website page (not the entire site just a single page) and all elements on the page, then sum the size of these files.

When I say files, I would like to know the total size of HTML, CSS, Images, local and remote JS files, and any CSS background images.  Basically the entire page-weight for a given page.

I thought about using CURL but was not sure how to enable it to grab remote and local JS files as well as images referenced in the CSS files.

Comment: Do you need to download the materials?  Or will firebug / webdev toolbar / Yslow give you that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `wget`:

- make it download all required files with `-p` or `--page-requisites` option
- download scripts and images local to the site and not further than 2 hops away (this should get local images and code) with `-l 2` for `--level=2`
- and change the code files to link to your local files instead of their original path with `-k` for `--convert-links`:

```
    wget -p -l 2 -k http://full_url/to/page.html
```

Comment: Close, but it does not seem to be grabbing the remote JS files, such as Google analytics.

Comment: @meme Try adding `-r -l 2`. That's in the man page around l.1320

Comment: this only seems to work for links in the local site, not remote urls

Comment: Confirmed it works for the most part but will not grab the remote JS files such as Google Analytics and Flash files, but it is close.